# Can a user with Contribute in a folder add a document when they have r/o for the library?

Tags: document-library, permissions, folder

Imagine User X is in Permission Group A.

A document library is created and Group A have **read permission only** on the library.

A folder is created in the document library and shared with User X with Contribute permissions - would this user have permission to add documents to this folder?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, this folder has now unique permissions and User X has now Contribute permissions here, so he can add, edit and delete files and folders.

Comment: If you are satisfied, select this as answer. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

**Yes**.

As the user has **Contribute** permissions on the folder, the user will be able to add the documents in this folder. Also user can do the following operations on the folder(as contribute permissions allow this operations):

**Can view, add, update, and delete list items and documents.**